# How to check if it is the first time a value is found in if statement inside a foreach iteration

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach, conditional-statements

Suppose I have an array.

`$array1 = array('John','Mike','Tim','Dan');`

Using a `foreach` iteration, I'm looping through `$array1`, performing a db query that returns either `true` or `false` so I have:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $dbQueryResult = true; // or false depending on iteration
    if($dbQueryResult === true){
        // HOW DO I CHECK IF IT IS THE FIRST TIME I'M GETTING HERE
    }
}
```

How do I check if it's the first time I'm getting a desired result in an `if` statement inside a `foreach` iteration like in the above example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a variable to keep that information in

```
$firstTime = true;

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $dbQueryResult = true; // or false depending on iteration
    if($dbQueryResult === true){
        // HOW DO I CHECK IF IT IS THE FIRST TIME I'M GETTING HERE
        if ( $firstTime ) {
            // do first time stuff

            $firstTime = FALSE;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Strange how the earlier, more logical answer doesn't get the upvote. Allow me to fix.

Comment: @Nick :) maybe because in its first iteration it was not quite so logical. When I read it back to myself I then made it more logical. Thanks for the vote though

Comment: Either way in its present form it is (at least to my mind) more logical and so should get the same votes.

Comment: This answer is better. Somehow I thought of mine as logical but it kinda messed up my brain the more I looked at it haha. So this should be the more upvoted.